# How do I exclude all nuget sub-packages from output in a vsproject

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I am building a plugin that should depend on its loader's system libs in F#.

```
In my vsproject I have the following:

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FSFramework" Version="1.0.0-preview-1">
            <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      
        <PackageReference Include="Veldrid" Version="4.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Veldrid.StartupUtilities" Version="4.8.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This correctly prevents FSFramework.dll from being written out, however the FSFramework nuget also pulls in FSharp.Core.dll which still gets written to the output.  If I try to put a PackageReference directly to FSsharp.Core.dll I end up with it twice and a build script error.

Comment: Is this problem specific to FSFramework? I tried it with other Nuget packages on .NET 5.0 and didn't have any problems. (FSFramework is .NET 6.0 only, which I don't have yet.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with plugins on .NET 6.0, but I'm not sure I can reproduce exactly what you're seeing. Do you have a GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem?

One bit of advice that seems important is to have the following element in your `PropertyGroup`:

```xml
<EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
```

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#plugin-with-library-dependencies) for more info.

Here's the full `.fsproj` for the plugin that works for me:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <WarnOn>3390;$(WarnOn)</WarnOn>
    <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="HelloCommand.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSFramework" Version="1.0.0-preview-1">
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\PluginBase\PluginBase.csproj">
          <Private>false</Private>
          <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
      </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you.   I went  on to something else but when i get back to this project I will try this!